# Return a paged DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-datatable, .net-2.0

Is there a better way to do it and have it be .Net 2.0 compatible?

```
public static DataTable GetErrorLog(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, string logPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
    {
        sortExpression = "fileName DESC";
    }

    DataTable errorLog = GetErrorLogDataTable();

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(logPath);
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        DataRow row = errorLog.NewRow();
        row["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        row["filePath"] = filePath;
        errorLog.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    DataView dataView = new DataView(errorLog);
    dataView.Sort = sortExpression;
    errorLog = dataView.ToTable();
    DataTable pagedErrorLog = errorLog.Clone();

    for (int i = startRowIndex; i < startRowIndex + maximumRows; i++)
    {
        if (i >= errorLog.Rows.Count)
        {
            break;
        }
        pagedErrorLog.ImportRow(errorLog.Rows[i]);
    }

    if (pagedErrorLog.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        return errorLog;
    }
    else
    {
        return pagedErrorLog;
    }
}

private static DataTable GetErrorLogDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("fileName");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("filePath");
    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Parameter validation

Because `GetErrorLog()` is a public method you should assume that any given parameter can be wrong so a at least basic validation should take place.

E.g assume a user of that method is passing a `startRowIndex == -1` then the line `pagedErrorLog.ImportRow(errorLog.Rows[i]);` would throw with an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

A much better way would be to validate that parameter at the beginning like so

```
if (startRowIndex < 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startRowIndex");
}
```

---

I would split that big method into several smaller ones which are having only one responsibility like

```
private static void FillErrorLogTable(DataTable table, string[] filePaths)
{
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["fileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        row["filePath"] = filePath;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}  

private static void FillPagedErrorLog(DataTable source, DataTable destination, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    int sourceRowCount = source.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++)
    {
        if (i >= sourceRowCount)
        {
            break;
        }
        destination.ImportRow(source.Rows[i]);
    }
}
```

How should `Rows.Count` at this condition `if (pagedErrorLog.Rows.Count <= 0)` ever be `< 0`? That won't ever happen.

Summing up the changes with only the mentioned validation which should be extended to validate the remaining parameters as well, would lead to

```
public static DataTable GetErrorLog(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string sortExpression, string logPath)
{
    if (startRowIndex < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startRowIndex");
    } 

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
    {
        sortExpression = "fileName DESC";
    }

    DataTable errorLog = GetErrorLogDataTable();

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(logPath);

    FillErrorLogTable(errorLog, filePaths);

    DataView dataView = new DataView(errorLog);
    dataView.Sort = sortExpression;
    errorLog = dataView.ToTable();
    DataTable pagedErrorLog = errorLog.Clone();

    FillPagedErrorLog(errorLog, pagedErrorLog, startRowIndex, startRowIndex + maximumRows);

    if (pagedErrorLog.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return errorLog;
    }
    else
    {
        return pagedErrorLog;
    }
}
```

Other than what I had mentioned, your code looks good, you are following the naming conventions and you have named your things well (except of the `GetErrorLogDataTable()` method which I would name `Create..`).